# Spark repartition zipped file input on read

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using `sc.textFile(path,partitions)` I'm able to partition uncompressed files as they are being read in.  Unfortunately for RDDs that are in zipped parts the `partitions` doesn't change when you set it.  Since downstream processing has to be in more parts I do `sc.textFile(path,partitions).repartition(partitions)` but it does a lot of shuffling.  Is there a way to just repartition locally?  That is, for every node they have instead break it into parts rather than randomly shuffling across the cluster.

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in solution or do you want to tinker with Spark core?

Comment: It would be ideal if this were possible out of the box.  Sounds like you're suggesting that it is impossible?

Comment: AFAIK. You can reduce data movement a little with smarter partitioning but it will be useful only if change is relatively small (lets say twice as much partitions). There are some internal mechanisms which theoretically could be useful but I am not sure if it make sense to go there.

Comment: Ok, do you think maybe this is just bad documentation or a bug in the functionality for zipped files?  Also, in general the spark support here is sparse.  Do you know of another site that has a more active spark community?

Comment: Now I feel offended :) Seriously though you can try user@spark.apache.org. I would say it is a feature. There are only a few when it could be useful without a shuffle.

Comment: No offense Intended.  You have been helpful, but in my other spark questions I also see very low number of views.  I'm not following why you believe it a feature?

Comment: Well, at the low level Spark operates on Iterators and can spill data to disk if needed. So as long as partitions are large but data is well distributed over the cluster it shouldn't be a huge issue. If data is not well distributed splitting locally wouldn't help at all to evenly distribute the work. It most likely means that cluster manger will try to move tasks to idle workers and go to the square one. If you want change number of partitions by a small factor (lets say not more than 2 or 3)  you can try to use custom partitioner to minimize  data movement.